# Custom Post Type Taxonomy Term Order by Title

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post type of Clients. The "Client Categories (taxonomy terms)" are called via taxonomy-client.php. I'm able to get the results to output as expected but I can't figure out how to get them to order by title. Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>    
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
<h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
<div class="content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Guess no one has an answer?  :(  I can't be the only one w/the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After about 100 different tries, I got it to work. Not sure if there is a better way, but it works.

```
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
    $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'clients',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'=>array(
            array(
            'taxonomy'=>$taxonomyName,
            'field'=>$term_slug,
            'terms'=> $current_term,
            )
        )
    );
<?php $query = new WP_Query($args); while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
//stuff here
<?php endwhile; ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```